# Looking for the best sorting + pipelining strategy for my situation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science, pipeline, heapsort

To begin, I have the set of K values S={v_1, ..., v_K}. I want to pick the smallest value, replace it with another value, and again pick the smallest -- do this K times. So, initially, my best set B is empty, and I want to perform :

Step 1. Find minimum of S. Say it has index n. B=[B, v_n] (i.e., append v_n to B)

Step 2. Update S by replacing v_n with another value (not important how that other value is computed).

Repeat Steps 1 and 2 till B has K values.

I believe a reasonable way to do this is to first construct a min-heap from the initial S (KlogK complexity), and then I can (take out the root + insert new element) for   (K-1) times. Assuming taking out root and insertion both are logK complexity, total complexity would be KlogK + 2(K-1)log(K) = (3K-2)logK.

As a next step, once I have the set B, I want to compute some function f(b) for each b in B,  and repeat the above procedure with the set {f(b)} instead of the set S. In other words, taking the set {f(b)} as S now, I would like to perform the above described procedure. Brute force way -- I could first use up (3K-2)logK units of time to find B, then compute the set {f(b)}, and then use another (3K-2)logK units of time on {f(b)}. But, it is quite apparent I can do better by pipelining. Essentially, as soon as I start getting entries of B, I can compute f(.) for the available entries, and do some of the sorting operations.

Can you suggest a good/optimal way for the overall problem ?

Comment: maybe you can do  B=[B, f(v_n)] instead?

Comment: Thanks. But I do need to construct B based on v_n's, not f(v_n)'s. f{B} is then another set for which I need to sort/replace/sort ...

Comment: so B is also part of output? Then will it help if you construct a new set S' = [S' f(v_n)] for next step?

Comment: Absolutely. As soon as I start getting the v_n's that go into B, I can start constructing the set S' by computing f(v_n). But what/how should the operations actually happen. Say I got first entry of B = b1 (= some v_n), I can immediately get S'=[f(b1)]. No sorting to do for S' yet. Now, it takes 2logK time units to get b2, and I then have S'={f(b1), f(b2)}. I can sort these two entries of S' now. What is a good way to sort/store them ? Should I start constructing a heap for S' also ? After another 2logK time units, I get b3. I can compute f(b3) now, and update the heap for S' using f (v3) ?

Comment: I think storing S' as a heap is a good choice. If you build S' in parallel, assuming f can be computed in constant time, total time needed for step 1 and 2 should be O(k log k) for k deletion and insertion to heap S, S'

Comment: Adding to previous comment: It seems using a heap for S' is certainly OK. The time (2logK) it takes to generate one new b, is more than enough to update the heap for S' (size of S' is always <=K, so adding a new element to this heap takes less than logK time, while I have 2logK time at my disposal). Clearly, this seems to achieve my best case scenario, where I have constructed the (initial) length K heap of S' in parallel with the operations on S to find B. So, my remaining processing time for S' now is (2K-2)logK.

Comment: Yes, I now read your last comment. Makes sense. Thank you !. Would appreciate one more comment from you: If we focus on just the set S and the construction of set B from it (i.e., if we ignore S' etc), then is my choice of using a heap the best strategy ? In other words, given set S, if I want to construct set B based on steps 1 and 2, can I do something better than "construct min-heap, remove root/add, remove root/add,..." which is costing  (3K-2)logK time units ?

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use your approach. But I am not sure if this is the best approach. It maybe helpful if you study how the distribution v_i because some value maybe not poped forever. However, it seems to me that you need at least k time unit so I think (3K-2)logK is a good starting point.